# Grub Rescue Error No Such Partition

Tags: grubrescue, partitioning

I accidently format my drive on which Ubuntu was installed. Now at the boot time it directly gives an error no partition grub rescue. I cannot istall any OS from my bootable usb drive. So anyone can give me a real solution for it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Start the computer with a Ubuntu live-dvd/usb.

Select try.

Initiated the live session.

Open a terminal.

Identify the drive running:

```
sudo su
fdisk -l
```

Suppose is /dev/sda, run:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Where:

```
if=/dev/zero - Read data from /dev/zero and write it to /dev/sda.
of=/dev/sda - /dev/sda is the drive to remove the MBR including all partitions.
bs=512 - Read from /dev/zero and write to /dev/sda up to 512 bytes at a time.
count=1 - Copy only 1 BLOCK input blocks.
```

Comment: i am not a techno guy then also i have make my usb ubuntu 14.04 bootable and tried to run it from the bios but after powering on it directly gives an error of no such partition grub rescue so any other solution

Comment: It is not working.Plz give me easy solution.